# What's the simplest (free) way to share a serial port over an ethernet link?

Tags: networking, ethernet, serial-port

I have two computers and I'd like to access the serial port on one machine from the other. Is it possible to do this with free software and if so, what options do I have?

The sharing machine is running Windows XP And the client machine is running Windows 7 x64

Comment: You may use [Serial to Ethernet Connector](http://eltima.com/products/serial-over-ethernet/) - the software, which shares serial port over network. It works on all Win platforms and on the Linux, if you will need it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work for you:

http://www.javiervalcarce.eu/html/sw-access-to-serial-port-from-internet-en.html

Basically is a c# app (source & compiled)

Comment: Nice tool.  BTW, there is an english translation linked in the upper-right hand corner of the page.

Comment: That's the server side sorted, but how would I make the port visible on the client end?

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with this [Virtual Serial Port](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html).  It is free as long as you respect the license.

Do main POS (Point of Sale) products and a lot of stuff still runs on Serial Ports.

Have used this program for a Video Overlay from a POS system to a CCTV/DVR system, and also as a PMS(Property managment system) for POS to Hotel.  (aka,  room charges.)

You install the software on both the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Total Commander, it is shareware so you can use it for evaluation, although it works fully even without a license.

It has support for linking computers via 'Serial Port's and also many excellent features.

Comment: This is the opposite of what the question asks.  The computers are already linked via Ethernet.  The objective is to access the other computer's serial port via the Ethernet connection.